# Download files in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I am trying to download a file (includes pdf, zip, images, etc) in C#.
I have tried the code in the following link.

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/252778

http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/haissam/archive/2007/04/03/Downloading-Files-C_2300_.aspx

It's working as expected in IE. But in Firefox the downloaded zip and image file is corrupted.

Comment: Corrupted how? What is the difference between expected and actual?  Also: in this scenario you aren't trying to download - you are serving a http response to a client, and prompting the client to treat it as a download - very different.

Comment: Are you doing any compression on server, may be in `Gloabl.asax`? If yes skip it for download request.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be with the FILENAME parameter in the Content-Disposition header.

You can try the sample code by following these rules:

- the filename should be in US-ASCII charset
- the filename should not have any directory path information specified
- the filename should not be enclosed in double quotes
- Content-Type header should refer to an unknown MIME type

  ```
  FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\picture.bmp");
  Response.Clear();
  Response.ContentType = "application/x-unknown";
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(fi.Name)));
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString());
  Response.TransmitFile(fi.FullName);
  Response.End();
  ```